# Best way to chown on newly created directory via mkdir -p

Tags: chown, mkdir

Suppose I did a

```
mkdir -p a/b/c/d
```

and directories a,b (a/b) already exists. so it will only create c/d.
Now I want to only change the owner of directories c and d not a and b using chown.

```
chown  -R user:group a/b/c/d
```

will change permission for a/b too which i dont want.

Whats the best way to do it? how do i find that c and d are newly created directories via mkdir -p so that i can chown them.

Comment: Your `chown` will only change user/group on folder d, so `chown -R user:group a/b/c` should do it if you don't need to know if c and d were newly created. You could add option `--from=$USER:$(id -gn)` to make the operation safer.

Comment: Don't use mkdir's -p option and use a loop. mkdir -p is here to get the job done faster. If it's slowing down the job, don't use it anymore

Comment: @Freddy yeah i know chown -R user:group a/b/c is the right answer but how can i find a/b/c from my mkdir -p a/b/c/d? any easy way for it? baciscally how to know which directories are being created by mkdir -p and which already exists.

Comment: @A.B thanks, that might be a work around.

Comment: `mkdir -v -p a/b/c/d` will tell you what was created. But the output might not be supposed to be parsed: if you have a non C / en_US locale you have to use LANG=C or maybe LANG=C.UTF-8 before. What about spaces and quotes (mkdir's output escapes them. how to unescape them?) etc